# Binding two server with one IP each to nameservers?

Tags: domain-name-system, hosting, nameserver

I have one VPS (example1.com ON 1.1.1.1) and one dedicated server (example2.com ON 1.1.1.2). 
I need to use my custom nameservers.

Currently I am using ns1.example1.com and ns2.example1.com both pointing to 1.1.1.1, but I have read that it is not best solution, as well as some local domains registars require that nameservers must be with different IP addresses.

Also, I have read on this web site that one nameserver should point to one server, and other to other server.

If that is true, do I need to point ns2.example1.com to 1.1.1.2, and will I be able to host websites on dedicated server, and which nameservers will I use? Do I need to use same nameservers or to create different for other server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea is you want to avoid having a single point of failure, such as a single server or a single route for traffic to travel down to improve reliability. By having everything one server you are greatly increasing your risk and making maintenance very difficult without being disrupting.

You often take it further than that. We have 8 servers, NS0,NS2 in the UK and NS1,NS3 in Germany. In the UK datacentre we have 4 servers, each nameserver is actually running on two servers redundantly, hence 4 servers. We also have redundant routers, firewalls, HA load balancers, WANs and power sources.

You should ideally have a minimum of two separate nameservers on two separate physical servers, ideally in two separate locations/regions/availability-zones.

So put NS1 on your vps and NS2 on your dedicated, with two separate IP addresses. I recommend BIND as it is straight forward once you know what you're doing and is very reliable. You then configure one as the master and one as a slave so any changes made on the master then replicate to the other.

If you are really on a tight budget you can pay for vanity nameservers from godaddy with your own domain name. This would be much more reliable and easier than hosting yourself. https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/683/creating-vanity-nameservers-in-premium-dns?countrysite=uk

---

In response to your question in the comments:

OK, so nameservers are accessed randomly, they should be identical.NS1 and NS2 should have website.com and website2.com.

So lets say we have:
WHM1 - 1.1.1.1
NS1
Webserver1

WHM2 - 1.1.1.2
NS2
Webserver2

Lets say you own website.com, you set the nameservers to NS1 & NS2

Your computer's DNS randomly picks one of them. If it picked NS2 and you only had the details on NS1 it would fail.

The websites and the nameservers are completely separate systems. You can have the nameservers on both servers but the website hosted on only one server.

You must put website.com on NS1 and NS2.
If you want website.com on both webservers as well you can add the following DNS records to the zone:

Domain.com

```
    @   14400 IN A 1.1.1.1
    @   14400 IN A 1.1.1.2
    www 14400 IN A 1.1.1.1
    www 14400 IN A 1.1.1.2
```

say you type in www.domain.com, you randomly go to either webserver 1 or webserver 2

Comment: Thank you for explanation. I have another question. Lets say I create ns1.example1.com and point it to 1.1.1.1 and ns2.example1.com to 1.1.1.2. If I want to host www.website.com to 1.1.1.1 and www.website2.com to 1.1.1.2 which nameserver should I use. Will I just put ns1 and ns2 to both and when I create accounts with WHM on both it will deliver correct website?

Comment: I can buy another IP for each server and create second nameserver on each server, but I dont know what is best solution. Also, I dont understand what is the advantage having other nameserver on separate server, because if it is on one server and server fails everything will fail too. Having it separated will do nothing better, if server fails websites will still be unavailable.

Comment: You only need one IP per server, answer is above

Comment: I understand I can point ns1 to vps and ns2 to dedicated. I am just wondering what will be nameservers for websites hosted on vps and what on dedicated. Will I use same nameservers ns1 and ns2 on both servers or ns1 and ns2 only for hosting on VPS and I need to create ns3 and ns4 for hosting on dedicated?

Comment: You should have everything on all nameservers.

Comment: Thank you for a thoroughly explanation. So this would mean I need to have 2 mirrored server, and it is not something that is best solution for me because of limited budget. I need so host different websites on one and different websites on other server and to use 2 nameservers. GoDaddy is offering vanity nameservers, but as I understand it is only for domains that are registered at GoDaddy. I am using some local domains. Now I am using ns1 and ns2 pointing to same IP, but some registers are rejecting that, and require different IP in nameservers.